# CODEIGNITER FOREACH

Tags: codeigniter, loops, model

I need to generate a monthly report using codeigniter. I have to post data results(if any) that will equal to the given month from January to December inside the loop.

Example:

> -----------January-------------
>   +name | email |records+
>   +asdgh|trtryjei|fguuyiuy+
>    ----------February------------
>   +name | email |records+
>   +asdgh|trtryjei|fguuyiuy+

`for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){

    //run the query here matching the date based on $i. 1 = January and so on. }`

I just have no idea how to implement this using codeigniter. I'll really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Whats your email i will help you in codeIgniter

Comment: @Venkat Why don't you just help him on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$curYear    = '2013';
for( $i=1; $i<13; $i++ ){
    for( $j=1; $j<32; $j++ ){
        $dateToday  = $curYear.'-'.$i.'-'.$j;
        #your query here
        $rs = $this->db->select('*')->where('date', $dateToday)->get('table');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main CI functions work like this :-

**result()**

This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;

   echo $row->name;

   echo $row->body;
}
```

The above function is an alias of result_object().

If you run queries that might not produce a result, you are encouraged to test the result first:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;

      echo $row->name;

      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```

You can also pass a string to result() which represents a class to instantiate for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->result('User') as $row)
{
   echo $row->name; // call attributes

   echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
}
```

**result_array()**

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];

   echo $row['name'];

   echo $row['body'];
}
```

**row()**

This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an object. Here's a usage example:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row();

   echo $row->title;

   echo $row->name;

   echo $row->body;

}
```